# mysql - double join (one from same table, one from different table)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

The "member" table:

> member_id, member_name, voter_id
>
> 1, ABC, 2
>
> 2, Fred, 0
>
> (So, Fred is the voter for ABC.)

The "billing" table:

> billing_id, member_id, billing_expiration
>
> 1, 1, 2012
>
> 2, 1, 2013
>
> 3, 1, 2014
>
> (So, ABC has made three annual payments and is paid up to 2014.)

I'm looking to generate a list of all members, but with an additional column "expiration" which shows when their highest-value expiration.  But -- here's the part I don't know how to do.  In addition to "ABC" showing "2014" as the "expiration", I want the "voter" member to show the same expiration value as the one found for the parent member (in this case, Fred would also show 2014, the highest value found).

AC

###### Update to earlier post

Here is the sql.  It is very slow, and also fails because the highest year is not returned.

```
    select member.*, corp.*, billing.billing_expires from member 


    left join member as corp          
    on (corp.voter_id = member.member_id)

    left join billing          
    on (corp.voter_id = billing.member_id)


    group by member.member_id
    order by billing.billing_expires desc
```

Comment: Please provide your SQL code and tell us what goes wrong.

Comment: Just updated the original post.  Thanks, showdev.

Comment: Avoid * if you don't need even one of the returned columns. For large datasets, performance gain will be surprising. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/366b9/19) a bit and came up with this solution:

```
select m.member_name as memb, c.member_name as corp,
  (select max(b.billing_expiration) from billing b
  where b.member_id = c.member_id
  or b.member_id = m.member_id) as expiration
from member m
left outer join member c on c.voter_id = m.member_id
```

The sub-select may be a bit slow too, though - depending on the size of your tables...